# What is Microsoft Warbird ( in Compiler of VS2015)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, obfuscation, compiler-optimization

Well recently i discovered in the compiler of Visual Studio 14 (2015) something called **Warbird**.

I googled for it but found nothing. Except maybe 4 reference in here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656776.aspx
like

> Compiler warning C4992    Warbird: function '%$pD' marked as
>   __forceinline not inlined because it contains inline assembly which cannot be protected

which are **undocumented**.

Regarding some string reference in 
`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\c2.dll` like

```
Warbird Transform Function Pre-lower
Warbird Transform Function Pre-Encode
```

somehow leads me to guess that **Warbird** is some code **obfuscating/protection system** that's build into the Microsoft compiler.

### Well is that true and if yes, how to use it?

In past the first time I encountered some mystic Microsoft obfuscating was when discovering the Windows XP Product Activation Check inside winlogon.exe. 
And for now there is this strangle with [**Kernel Patch Protection**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection) in 64-bit Windows that tries to keep of drivers messing with the Kernel.

*Reverse Engineering in progress...*

Comment: Surely the internal name of a project at Microsoft.  It is never supposed to be obvious after it is done but they don't always get that right.  Several possible candidates for VS2015, but the biggest one was the complete rewrite of the front-end to make it C++1x compliant.  This is not going to change the way you write code.

Answer (score 4):

Warbird is a code protection framework from Microsoft, apparently developed more than 10 years ago. There are now a few sources documenting it:

- Alex Ionescu's talk at Ekoparty conference in 2017, talk is on YouTube: [The "Bird" That Killed Arbitrary Code Guard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu_i6LYuePg). He mentioned the Visual Studio hidden parameters you noticed.
- [Alexandre Gazet's analysis of a virtual-machine based protection produced by old Warbird versions](https://github.com/airbus-seclab/warbirdvm)

Answer (score 0):

According to [ThisIsSecurity.net](https://thisissecurity.net/2014/10/15/warbird-operation/) research:

> Warbird is an enhancement of the license verification of Windows that is introduced in Windows 8/2012. The former system was too easy to intercept and to fake, so Microsoft decided to provide something that is harder to reverse engineer and to fake.

Some dlls for VBA also have reference to Warbird, for example in `VBEUI.dll`

```
Warbird Code Verification Hook
Warbird Hooks
Warbird Heap Execution Hook
```